# Why won't my crankshaft turn a full rotation?

Tags: pulley, crankshaft

I have a 95 Camry LE (v6) and I'm in the process of replacing the water pump.  One of the prerequisites for accessing the pump is crank pulley removal.  User cdunn (thanks a bunch for the suggestions) provided me with info on the starter bump method for crank bolt removal (since I don't have an impact gun) and managed to fail at every attempt.  When filming myself doing this, I would turn over the engine with the camera facing the crank bolt.  I noticed that when the socket was on the bolt (and socket attached to breaker bar which is snug against my control arm) and I bump the starter, the crank doesnt make a full revolution...it seems to either get stuck - like theres not enough torque - or it senses something blocking it and doesnt turn.  After removing the socket, and bumping the starter with nothing on the bolt, the crankshaft turns fine...help!

Comment: Have you got the bolt out now using the starter?

Comment: Are you sure that you're rotating the engine the right way? Remember that your bolt is going to be removed counter-clockwise. The engine needs to turn clock wise so that they can cohesively work together. If the engine is a counter-clockwise running motor, it will not work. I'm not sure on those V6's which way they go.

Comment: @HandyHowie negative it won't turn enough

Comment: @cloudnyn3  yes I observed the crank turn clockwise during a test run without the socket on

Comment: @NathanielDavidson Unless the bolt is seized inside the crank, I don't think it has anything to stop it from turning. Other than a dead battery. If you removed your timing components that could be causing it to hangup if pistons are hitting valves. That starter should have more than enough power to break a bolt loose.

Comment: Are yo certain the bolt has a right hand thread?

Comment: @cloudnyn3 nice catch!  I forgot to mention that my battery needs a jump every now and then, and I'm getting a new battery later on today... Does a weak battery=weak turn?

Comment: @NathanielDavidson Yes it can. Having 12v Doesn't mean you're achieving the rated cold cranking amps of the battery. The fact that it needs jumps everyone once in a while is a red flag. Never hurts to have a new battery anyway. I'm not sure if anyone mentioned it, but there are flywheel stoppers for this exact purpose. Toyota special service tools aren't too expensive. They're called (SST). You may want to look into that if the new battery doesn't help. I have quite the collection of these and they are always easier than shadetree methods. If it's not too expensive I would invest in it lol

Answer (score 7):

**This is compression of air working against you**

Over the course of two crank revolutions for your Camry you have 4 cylinders compressing air and fuel.  When you see the engine get to a point of rotation and it rotates backward a bit after releasing the starter, that's air acting as a spring and resisting.

If you take your sparkplugs out of the engine it will allow the engine to turn over without working against your efforts.

This is normal behavior, nothing's wrong.

Comment: Thanks I will try that in a few hours , after work. Thanks!